# How could I lighten/darken a hex color in C?

Tags: c, colors

Note: I'm still pretty new to C. I'm trying to write a little C utility that takes in a hex color from stdin or an argument and a flag to dictate if the color should be darkened or lightened, and by what percentage. How should I go about doing the lightening or darkening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to read data and modify it or about color theory?

Comment: More about color theory. I'm not looking for a perfect algorithm, just a "good enough" one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it right, first decode the hex values into three integers, `r`, `g`, and `b`, convert to doubles, then convert those doubles into a different 3D colorspace in which lightness or intensity is its own element. Either HSL/HSV or YIQ/YUV (Google "color space"). Then change the intensity, and convert back. That will ensure that you get a darker version of the same hue with the same saturation (more or less--at least it will be much better than simply tweaking the RGB values). Google "RGB to HSL" and such to find code for doing the conversions.

For example:

https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256

Answer (score 0):

Hex color is simply 3 bytes (00-FF) for Red, Green, and Blue.
#000000 is Black, #FFFFFF is white. Therefore you need to read those 3 bytes from standard input, store as integers, divide/multiply for specific given percentage(i.e *1.20 = increase by 20%), take mod FFFFFF and you got your result color.

Comment: Instead of mod, clamping between 0 and FFFFFF inclusive would probably be more reasonable.

Comment: That will change the hue and saturation as well as lightness. Better to convert first, then change, the convert back.

Comment: If you are multiplying the only obvious thing to do is mod. Don't create a from-nothing argument there, it's clearly not the place to explain about the hyperbolic map, so that brightening was smooth, etc.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker lightening / darkening _necessarily_ changes saturation and lightness...

Comment: Guys, this is a beginner programming question. Color theory has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @bedbad who said anything about "hyperbolic map"?! just `max(0, min(channel * percentage, 0xFF))`

Comment: Color theory has everything to do with it, and darkening/lightening a color properly will not change the hue or saturation significantly except at the extremes.

Comment: Modulo would cause a value just above brightest to be very dark. Saturating (the min approach suggested) is a reasonable solution, even if not perfect. Mod is a bad idea.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: multiplying by a value smaller than 1 will always correctly darken a color, no need for complications there. Brightening is the difficult thing, which requires using the right color space. Not all definitions of HSL/HSV are suitable, some have reduced ranges for S as L or V increases.